# Maintaining same TCP connection for entire run in JMeter

Tags: tcp, jmeter

I have 500 threads in my test plan and duration is set to 20 minutes. 500 users have been created 37000 samples with 37000 TCP connections. Jmeter creating a new connection for every new request it sends.We need 500 users creating 500 TCP connections and those 500 connections should be maintained for entire run.
PLease suggest how can I achieve this in JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is going for [HTTP Raw Request](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/) sampler, it has `Keep connection open` checkbox so you will be able to re-use the same connection for the virtual user for the series of the TCP requests.

[image: JMeter HTTP Raw Request Keep Connection]

You can install HTTP Raw Request sampler using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have downloaded this and applied it in my script. But, I am seeing an error 400 and Invalid header in the response. I have given my hostname,TCP Port and kept connection as open. Please help

Comment: I am not telepathic enough to guess what is wrong without seeing at least your request so I can recommend only capturing 2 requests: one from normal TCP Sampler and another one from the HTTP Raw Request with a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and then amend the latter one configuration to match the first one

Comment: OK. It would be helpful to me, If you could tell what information do I need to keep in Request data field.

Comment: The same as for the TCP Sampler

Answer (score 0):

Check TCP Sampler >> "Re-use Connection" option.

> If " Re-use connection " is selected, connections are shared between
>   Samplers in the same thread, provided that the exact same host name
>   string and port are used. Different hosts/port combinations will use
>   different connections, as will different threads. If both of " Re-use
>   connection " and " Close connection " are selected, the socket will be
>   closed after running the sampler. On the next sampler, another socket
>   will be created. You may want to close a socket at the end of each
>   thread loop. If an error is detected - or " Re-use connection " is not
>   selected - the socket is closed. Another socket will be reopened on
>   the next sample